# How to reverse direction on only one specific column with google chart (combo chart)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I already reversed the column bars from top to bottom but I want the one column bar to be not reversed for some reason. I lost ideas how to achieve this.

It should look from this.

[Google chart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHRSN.png)

to this.

[Google chart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnJMS.png)

see the **Effective** column

codepen:
https://codepen.io/jayrexacilo/pen/PBQwWQ

html:

```
<div id="call_analysis_container">
  <div class="chart-title bg-blue">Call analysis</div>
  <div id="call_analysis" style="width: 80%; height: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCallAnalysis);
function drawCallAnalysis() {
    var dataArr = [
      ["Analysis", "Calls", { role: "style" } ],
      ["Target Calls", 350, "#FFFF00"],
      ["On Route Calls", 185, "#00B050"],
      ["Off Route", 35, "#B1A0C7"],
      ["Calls not Made", 17, "#000000"],
      ["Effective", 120, "#E26B0A"]
    ];
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArr);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,
                     { calc: "stringify",
                      sourceColumn: 1,
                      type: "string",
                      role: "annotation" },
                     2]);

    var options = {
      title: "",
      seriesType: 'bars',
      legend: { position: "none" },
      backgroundColor: '#4F81BD',
      vAxis: {
          textStyle: {color: '#4F81BD'},
          viewWindowMode:'none',
            viewWindow:{
              max:350,
              min:0
            },
          gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent',
            count: 8
          },
          direction: '-1'
        },
        enableInteractivity: false
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("call_analysis"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

Comment: usually these libraries are not customizable. did u try to change the order of your data in that specific column?

Comment: i didn't, i just tried to re position the bar from the bottom because the height is already there. the problem is putting it to the bottom

Comment: it should be working if u give it a negative value but it doesnt. fine another library or write it yourselfe. bar charts are so easy to write in d3.js.

Comment: check this  https://bl.ocks.org/datafunk/8a17b5f476a40a08ed17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in google charts, the only way to reverse the direction of a single column is to have two series of data
then you can assign one of the series to a different axis, and reverse the direction of the new axis

the problem with this approach is the additional series will cause the columns to be off center,
because it is expecting two columns, but we only want one.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCallAnalysis);
function drawCallAnalysis() {
  var dataArr = [
    ["Analysis", "Calls", { role: "style" } , "Calls", { role: "style" } ],
    ["Target Calls", 350, "#FFFF00", null, null],
    ["On Route Calls", 185, "#00B050", null, null],
    ["Off Route", 35, "#B1A0C7", null, null],
    ["Calls not Made", 17, "#000000", null, null],
    ["Effective", null, null, 120, "#E26B0A"]
  ];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArr);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }, 2, 3, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 3,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }, 4]);

  var options = {
    title: '',
    seriesType: 'bars',
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    backgroundColor: '#4F81BD',
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {color: '#4F81BD'},
      viewWindowMode: 'none',
      viewWindow: {
        max: 350,
        min: 0
      },
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent',
        count: 8
      }
    },
    vAxes: [
      {direction: -1},
      {direction: 1}
    ],
    series: {
      1: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    },
    enableInteractivity: false
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('call_analysis'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="call_analysis"></div>
```

---

a better approach might be to draw two charts, side-by-side...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCallAnalysis);
function drawCallAnalysis() {
  var dataArr = [
    ["Analysis", "Calls", { role: "style" } ],
    ["Target Calls", 350, "#FFFF00"],
    ["On Route Calls", 185, "#00B050"],
    ["Off Route", 35, "#B1A0C7"],
    ["Calls not Made", 17, "#000000"],
    ["Effective", 120, "#E26B0A"]
  ];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArr);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }, 2]);

  var viewa = new google.visualization.DataView(view);
  viewa.setRows([0, 1, 2, 3]);
  var viewb = new google.visualization.DataView(view);
  viewb.setRows([4]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {fontSize: 12}
    },
    chartArea: {
      width: '100%'
    },
    title: '',
    seriesType: 'bars',
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    backgroundColor: '#4F81BD',
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {fontSize: 12},
    },
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {color: '#4F81BD'},
      viewWindowMode: 'none',
      viewWindow: {
        max: 350,
        min: 0
      },
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent',
        count: 8
      },
      direction: '-1'
    },
    enableInteractivity: false
  };

  options.width = 100 * viewa.getNumberOfRows();
  var charta = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('call_analysis_a'));
  charta.draw(viewa, options);

  options.vAxis.direction = 1;
  options.width = 100 * viewb.getNumberOfRows();
  var chartb = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('call_analysis_b'));
  chartb.draw(viewb, options);
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #4F81BD;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chart {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="chart" id="call_analysis_a"></div>
  <div class="chart" id="call_analysis_b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man! :D i made my own approach but your two solutions way more better than I have now. maybe, i'll use the second one :)